# Will code produce a race condition?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, race-condition

I have a file with a base path to all my resources. For example:

```
build/scripts/script1.js  
build/scripts/script2.js
```

I of course need a base path for example:

```
https://example.org/SuperDuperSite/build/scripts/script1.js
```

What i was hoping to do was load the file into a global dictionary at startup with the path. The dictionary would only have to be loaded once. Unfortunately, as far as i can tell, the base path is not available until the first request. So in asp.net i have to use `application_beginrequest` rather than `application_start`. What is bad about this is now I have to deal with multithreading issues.

which forces me to write the following type of code:

```
  lock(_lock) {
    if (_dictionary == null) {
        LoadDictionary();
    }
  }
```

This would be called for every single request when I only really need to load it once. I really don't like this of course. I don't want to have to lock on every single request for performance reasons. One solution, after talking to colleges that we came up with:

```
if (_dictionary == null)
{
   lock(_lock) {
      if (_dictionary == null) {
         LoadDictionary();
      }
    }
}
```

So with this solution I would not be required to lock on every single request but if multiple threads ended up getting this section on startup I would then protect it by checking if the object is null again inside the lock. Will this code work or am I going to run into a race condition?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of complexity to include a base url. Is there a reason you went the path of loading it into a dictionary at startup?

Comment: Are you sure you are attacking this from the right angle?  Is there a reason you can't do relative path requests?

Comment: Double checked locking is safe in c#. Conditions in code sample are backward, but other fine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes your right conditions are backwards. its just sudo code. I will fix. Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidL not sure :) but i can't hard code my paths because the file names change (they include hash in the file name for long term caching reasons). So i have to read a file outputed by webpack to determine what the file names are at runtime

Comment: Relative pathing isn't hardcoding. It's simply building a request off of the root of the application to avoid these (and other) types of issues.  You can at least do that to get the base and move on from there.

Comment: This is the standard answer to the lazy instantiation in a multithreaded situation problem.  You can't get a race.  The first null test saves you from the cost of a lock if it's already been built, the test within the lock keeps you from building it twice if two threads manage to get past the initial null check at the same time.

Comment: Looks like a common *double-checked lock* pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking, should not introduce any unwanted issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when using *double-checked locks*.

Yes, it's thread-safe, but in *your particular code* you might run into a subtle bug where `_dictionary` has been **instantiated** by the other thread (passing the `null` check), but not fully **populated** yet, and you may end up attempting to access a partially populated dictionary. And end up with one of these two:

1. You're missing results when reading the dictionary, or worse
2. Unless you're using a `ConcurrentDictionary` (which also comes with its performance implications), you may be reading and writing simultaneously to the dictionary, and causing a deadlock (yes, the `Dictionary` class is known to cause deadlocks in many a code).

A `bool _dictionaryLoaded` flag (double-checked), flipped to `true` at the end of `LoadDictionary()`, is probably better.

Or use [Lazy<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're on .NET 4. It's much cleaner, all you have to do is pass in `LoadDictionary` to be used as the init function.

Edit: Lazy<> is [internally implemented with a double-checked lock](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_LazyT).